# DateTime.ParseExact - UK date and time

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse the following UK format `DateTime` string: `24/01/2013 22:00`

However, I keep getting this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` returns "`en-GB`" which is correct

Here is my code

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDateTimeParse()
    {
        DateTime tester = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013 22:00", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        int hours = tester.Hour;
        int minutes = tester.Minute;

        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe the culture makes much difference when you're using `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`hh` is for 12 hour clocks. You should be using `HH` instead.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013 22:00", 
                    "d/M/yyyy HH:mm", // <-- here
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 5):

`"hh"` is for *The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12*

`"HH"` is for *The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23*

Try with like this;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime tester = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013 22:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/3KIIza).

Also you can check out [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: That's correct, but it would be good to _explain_ why. (btw - the `dd` and `MM` are not strictly required).

Comment: @Oded You are right but you already explained good the reason of _why_. Because if I write it also, is it seems copying ? (Yeah `dd` and `MM` are not necessary but this seems to me more readable than `d` and `M`)

Comment: I don't know about copying, but trying to make every answer the best possible one is not a bad goal to have, is it?

Comment: @Oded Of course you are right. But sometimes, when you write the nearly same thing with high rep guys, they blame you as a copying their answer and rep fishing. That's not cool of course..

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong, try this:

```
DateTime tester = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013 22:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```